# Clean up XML of a DOCX document with python / Linux binary

Tags: python, xml, linux, docx

It could be some kind of question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752932/simplify-clean-up-xml-of-a-docx-word-document)

But methods described there aren't applicable to my situation. I'm looking for a tool to use from Python or just a standalone Linux binary. All, that I've already found are only Win/MSO-related methods:(

Is there any way to simply clean docx tags in Linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to use headless LibreOffice as a convertor from DOCX to DOCX and it seemed to help with most of the cases.

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to docx ./Copyright\ license.docx
```

Nevertheless, this way needs more testing.